# wordpress - gutenberg block stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

We had a working custom gutenberg block written as a plugin for over a year. Out of nowhere it stopped working tonight and it gives us this message:

*Your site doesn't include support for the "blockname" block. You can leave this block intact or remove it entirely.*

What could go wrong with it to suddenly it stopped working? Where could I found the problem?

Comment: Have you confirmed the custom block plugin is still installed and active?

Comment: Yes, it is still installed and active.

Comment: is the custom block available to add to other posts/pages?  if yes, do you get the same error message when adding the custom block to other posts/pages?

Comment: can you please check your custom blocks plugin support for WordPress's latest version?